# Simple update statement not working with some parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

```
UPDATE DynamicsAx.dbo.LEDGERJOURNALTRANS 
SET PAYMENTSTATUS = 3
WHERE JOURNALNUM = @param1 AND DATAAREAID = @param2
```

It was not updating the record and the payment status remains unchanged as 5

```
SELECT PAYMENTSTATUS, * 
FROM DynamicsAx.dbo.LEDGERJOURNALTRANS 
WHERE JOURNALNUM = @param1 AND DATAAREAID = @param2
```

[image: SQL RESULT]

Comment: Your update statement points to DynamicsAx.dbo.LEDGERJOURNALTRANS  And select statement points to DynamicsAx2. 
These 2 statements point to 2 different databases. Seems like typo. Please check

Comment: Run Commit statement after update and check if that resolve the issue.

Comment: I have tried putting BEGIN TRAN & COMMIT TRAN but not working

Comment: May be the parameters `@param1` & `@param2` are not as expected. Are you using this inside Stored procedure or something? If so, print these parameters and check once. Also does the Direct update works *(without parameters)* ?

Comment: I have tried the original values in place of params still not updating the record.

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it.

Comment: Can you please share the table structure as well.

Comment: It is sql INT Datatype

Comment: After your update statement, run `SELECT @@ROWCOUNT` to verify rows were actually updated.  If so, then check for any table triggers on LEDGERJOURNALTRANS that might be interfering with your UPDATE.

Comment: Select @@rowcount showing 1 but still the data is not updated